# How to Use NumPy 1.4 Polynomial Class to Fit Values

Tags: python, numpy

How do you use the new Polynomials sub-package in numpy to give it new x values and get an output of y values?
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.package.html

In prior versions of numpy it went something like this:

```
poly = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 3)
new_x = np.linspace(0, 100)
new_y = poly(new_x)
```

The new version I am struggling to give it x values that give me the y values of each?

```
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

poly = Polynomial(Polynomial.fit(x, y, 3))
```

When I give it an array of x it just returns the coefficients.

Comment: rh109019, any luck getting some information about this? I'm stuck here as well. Tks.

Comment: @H.L. - a user answered correctly below. There is no need to wrap the fit method in Polynomial. You can fit then call the object with a new array of x and it will return an array of y values.

Answer (score 5):

You can directly call the resulting series to evaluate it:

```
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
poly = Polynomial.fit(x, y, 3)

new_y = poly(new_x)
```

Check [this page of the documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.classes.html) it has several examples.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, the answer by @Joan Charmant and the supportive comment @rh109019 do not work.

The intuitive way suggested by @Joan Charmant is, basically, what the question's about: it doesn't work.

Evidently, there is a new method introduced in *[numpy.polynomial.polynomial](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/routines.polynomials.polynomial.html)* devoted specifically to evaluating polynomials. See [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval).

Here's my code where I'm comparing the two approaches.

```
import numpy as np

Pgauge = np.asarray([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0])
NIST = np.asarray([1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 6.1, 7.1, 8.1])

calibrationCurve = np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(Pgauge,
                                                           NIST,
                                                           deg=1
)

print("The polynomial: {}".format(calibrationCurve))

x = np.asarray([0, 1]) # values of x to evaluate the polynomial at
c = calibrationCurve.coef # coefficients of the polynomial

print("The intuitive (wrong) way: {}".format(calibrationCurve(x)))
print("The correct way: {}".format(np.polynomial.polynomial.polyval(x, c)))
```

The first `print` command prints out the polynomial:`4.6+3.5x`.

If we want to evaluate it at the points `0` and `1` (`x = np.asarray([0, 1])`), we expect to get `4.6` and `8.1` respectively.

The second `print` command (that reads "*The intuitive (wrong) way*"), uses the method suggested by @Joan Charmant. It gives `[0.1, 1.1]` as the result. Which is wrong. Though seemingly, it looks ok: it gives two numbers as expected. But the numbers themselves are wrong. I don't know how these numbers were calculated. But if I had a bigger series of data, I wouldn't go with a calculator through it and assume I've got a correct result.

The last `print` command makes use of the `polyval` method suggested in the user manual that I cited above. And it works perfectly well. It gives `[4.6, 8.1]` as the result.

---

---

It so happens that my answer is wrong as well (see all the comments below by @user2357112 supports Monica).

But still, I'll leave it here for the folks who, like me, fell the victim of the confusing new *numpy.polynomial* library.

FIRST: why my code is wrong?

Everything's ok with it. But the line `print("The polynomial: {}".format(calibrationCurve))` doesn't give me what, I think, it must give me. It takes the correct polynomial, changes its coefficients somehow and prints out a new polynomial with the changed coefficients. Still, it does store the correct polynomial in its memory and when you do the thing suggested by @Joan Charmant it may give you the correct answer if you ask it properly.

SECOND: how to use the new *numpy.polynomial* library in order to get a correct result?

Due to that peculiarity, you have to introduce a new line of code. Namely, do the `Polynomial.fit()` and immediately afterwards use the `.convert()` method. Then work with the converted polynomial only.

Here's my code that works correctly now.

```
import numpy as np

Pgauge = np.asarray([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0])
NIST = np.asarray([1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.1, 5.1, 6.1, 7.1, 8.1])

calibrationCurveMessedUp = np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(Pgauge,
                                                                   NIST,
                                                                   deg=1
)

calibrationCurve = calibrationCurveMessedUp.convert()

print("The polynomial: {}".format(calibrationCurve))
print("The rounded polynomial coefficients: {}".format(calibrationCurve.coef))

x = np.asarray([0, 1]) # values of x to evaluate the polynomial at
print(calibrationCurve(x))
```

THIRD: a little note.

Apparently, there is a possibility to get the correct polynomial without the additional line of code. Probably, you have to give the correct `window` and `domain` parameters to the `Polynomial.fit()` function. Or may be there is another way.

If anybody knows such a way, you're welcome to edit my current answer and add your code.

Comment: No, `calibrationCurve(x)` is correct. The problem is that you're missing the (weird, confusing, not even shown in the `format` output) `domain` and `window` of the polynomial.

Comment: If you fit these inputs and outputs yourself (easy, because it's just a simple linear function), you'll find the relationship is y = x + 0.1, far from the y = 3.5x + 4.6 that `calibrationCurve` appears to be. The fitted polynomial looks so strange because `numpy.polynomial.Polynomial.fit` involves an automatic input scaling step, and this scaling is encoded in the `domain` and `window` of the `Polynomial` object.

Comment: The polynomial represents a fit over the transformed inputs, and applying the polynomial to new inputs with `calibrationCurve(x)` applies the same transformation before evaluating the polynomial.

Comment: If you look at the output of `calibrationCurve(x)` and compare it to `Pgauge` and `NIST`, you'll find it perfectly matches the `NIST` values, as it should for an exact fit. In comparison, the `4.6` and `8.1` values you expected from looking at the polynomial coefficients don't look anything like the relationship represented by `Pgauge` and `NIST`.

Comment: See [this documentation section](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.classes.html#fitting) for more on the motivation behind `window` and `domain`.

Comment: To get a polynomial that doesn't have this scaling and shifting, you can use `converted_polynomial = calibrationCurve.convert()`. If you do that and examine the result, you can see that the result represents a polynomial x + 0.1.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30701905)

Comment: @JeffUK I know how to ask questions. And why do you recommend deleting my answer? I'm telling you: the answer by @Joan Charman isn't any good. It doesn't mention `window` and `domain`. I followed Joan's suggestion and ended up having a wrong result! My answer and the comments bellow help to clarify what `window` and `domain` are for and how *Polynomial.fit* is different from *poly1d*. My answer and comments to it are crucial in understanding the caveats of *Polynomial.fit*. Try Joan's suggestion with my example and see that it gives wrong result. My answer should not be deleted.

Comment: @IvanNepomnyashchikh this isn't a forum, you're using an 'answer' to ask lots of 'questions' if your comments are needed to understand Joan's answer, they should be comments underneath that answer.

Comment: @JeffUK I ask only one question which I can delete easily from my post. I've just tried adding a comment to the Joan's post and failed (not enough reputation). Anyways, a comment will inevitably be brief. Whereas, my answer is a detailed explanation which is always better. Do we care about better understanding or exact following the rules? Moreover, the comments by *user2357112* to my post are very important themselves. It will be a loss if we delete them along with the post. Also, we are supposed to discuss this matter in the chat (which I don't know how to access to be honest).